# Fatal error: Call to a member function data_seek() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I keep getting this message, 
I suspect an error in my sql query, although I'm inexperienced with  php and sql, so my suspicions may not be very useful.

```
  public function verify_emp_credentials ($user)
    {
          $user= $this->real_escape_string($user);

          $result = $this->query("SELECT 1 FROM eddy WHERE id =" . $user);

           return $result->data_seek(0); //this is the line referenced
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is verify that the input passed from an html form , 
matches a record on the db..
Appreciate any feedback 
Thank you.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have done the changes you suggested. I have also corrected a problem in the query, which was causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the query returns a valid result set.

```
public function verify_emp_credentials($user) {
    $user = $this->real_escape_string($user);
    if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT 1 FROM eddy WHERE id = ' . $user)) {
        $data = $result->data_seek(0);
        $result->close();
        return $data;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Also I have no idea if your query is valid at all. Did you test that first to make sure it returns a valid result?

Comment: Ok, well a +1 would be nice to negate the -1 I got for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

There are is so much wrong with your code that it's simpler to write a brand new one rather than fix current.

Some highlights:

1. Use [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info), not mysqli.
2. DO NOT extend your application class from db API class
3. Use prepared statements.
4. Do not use functions you have no idea on.

So, make it

```
public function verify_emp_credentials ($user)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM eddy WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$user]);
    return $stmt->fetchColumn(); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check your "CHARACTER SET" . I think its different when you created your tables and different when you sent query .